# How can I translate this if/else statement into a while loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to convert this if/else statement into a while loop but have no idea what to do. Could someone help me with problem?

```
int no = 0;
    if        ((piece(0) == no) && (piece(1) == no) && (piece(2) == no) && (piece(3) == no)
            || (piece(1) == no) && (piece(2) == no) && (piece(3) == no) && (piece(4) == no)
            || (piece(2) == no) && (piece(3) == no) && (piece(4) == no) && (piece(5) == no)
            || (piece(3) == no) && (piece(4) == no) && (piece(5) == no) && (piece(6) == no)
            || (piece(4) == no) && (piece(5) == no) && (piece(6) == no) && (piece(7) == no)) {
        System.out.println("True");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("False");
```

Comment: An if/else statement is **not** a loop. Please explain what you mean. Because I also have no idea what to do.

Comment: Well, pick up a good book and read how loops work. You could use a for loop, or a while loop that uses some counter. In other words: look at code that uses loops. Enhance those examples. **Understand** the idea of loops, then applying it to your problem will come by itself.

Comment: A while loop to emulate an if-else block? You're going to tie the bytecode in knots!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a submethod

```
public boolean checkFourInARow(int seed) {
  return piece(seed) && piece(seed + 1) && piece(seed + 2) && piece(seed + 3)
}
```

Then replace the code you have posted with

```
while (int i < 5) {
  checkForInARow(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a while loop, but two for loops could reduce some of your redundancy:

```java
void foo()
{
    outer:
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < i + 4; ++j)
        {
            if (piece(j) != 0) continue outer;
        }
        System.out.println("True");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("False");
}
```